# php query causes 404 error

Tags: php, wordpress, http-status-code-404

I have been using the code below to post blog posts.

```
<?php query_posts('cat=35'); ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<a>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title();  ?>"><?php                the_title();    ?></a>
```

I noticed that my site was not being indexed by google. So I used the web testing tools at http://www.webpagetest.org/

The test returns a 404 code which means Google thinks the page do not exist.

I also noticed that my other sites which use the same code do not get 404 errors and are indexed by Google.

The problem is now happening when I put the code on plain page

All the blog posts exist and are displayed properly and the website itself exists and loads quickly

What is causing the 404 error ?

Comment: can you share your site URL?

Comment: You have `<a>`. You're clearly missing the `href`. It should read as `<a href="...">`. Unless you left that out/typo.?

Comment: Is it possible that not having the **endwhile;** at the end of your while loop could be causing the problem?

Comment: Try `<a href="page.php" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>` - **page.php** being the page's link in question.

Comment: Hi Phil

The test page is located here :

http://kenyapage.net/basket/index4.php

The blog is located at http://www.kenyapage.net/commentary

The test page has no other text besides the php query.

I am using http://www.webpagetest.org/ to test it and it returns a 404 error

Comment: Hi Mat
Actually I do have an end while. Looks like I may not have pasted the full code. Here it is again

<?php
require('../path/wp-blog-header.php');
?>

<?php query_posts('cat=35'); ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<a>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>

<?php endwhile;?>

Comment: Hi Fred
I used your suggestion and replaced page.php with index.php. I am still getting the 404 error

Comment: @VinceTaylor Ok. Well, you're still missing an `href`, so that's part of the problem.

Comment: Hi Fred
Is this what you would suggest ?

   <?php
require('../commentary/wp-blog-header.php');
?>

<?php query_posts('showposts=8'); ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
<a href="index.php" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a> 
<?php endwhile;?>